# Adding Numbers to Drop down in backbonejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, backbone.js

I'm working on project previously build on Backbonejs and MVC. I'm new to backbone

Now I need to replace the one textbox with drop down in MVC view

```
<input type="text" data-field-key="totalExp" id="user-data-total-exp" class="form-control disabled-for-edit-locked" value="" />
```

i replace with

```
<select id="exp-year" class="form-control exp-year">
                                    <option value=''>Years</option>
                                </select>
```

but in backbone View they masked the textbox to accept only digits

```
 function ($, _, FormView) {
    var EditExternalUserView = FormView.View.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {this.$("#user-data-total-exp, #user-data-relevant-exp").mask("00.00", { reverse: true });//some other code}
```

How can I bind the data to drop down at view or model of backbonejs

just i need to show 0-12 numbers in that dropdown.

Comment: Are you looking to populate data (0-12 numbers) in dropdown? I'm not sure i understand the question correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution for this,

```
this.model.set("Nameofdropdown", _.range(0, 12));
```

Comment: The question is not even clear. I don't think this is going to help anyone in future... consider deleting such questions...